# How to execute a function at the nth second of every minute?

Tags: python, datetime

time.sleep(60) is oblivious to the time.

So how to get python to execute a function at say the 50-second mark of every minute?

EDIT: I mean I want my function to be executed at:

```
-20:00:50
-20:01:50
-20:02:50
and so on...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeat python function at every system clock minute](/q/70799693/4518341)

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks for that! 
I've been trying to word it correctly but still couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a loop:

```
while True:
    my_function()
    time.sleep(50)
```

Comment: That will execute at (say) 20:00:00, 20:00:50, 20:01:40, 20:02:30...

Comment: Ah my bad, I misunderstood the question